# SessionStorage me retorna nulo

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy tratando de enviar un dato por sessionstorage, pero al capturarlo me retorna null

de esta forma lo estoy enviando

```
var win = window.location = urlactual+'vistas/menu.html';
win.focus();
sessionStorage.setItem("Token",token);
```

estoy enviando el siguiente dato

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiJhZG1pbiIsIm5iZiI6MTY3MjM1MTI1NCwiZXhwIjoxNjcyNDM3NjU0LCJpYXQiOjE2NzIzNTEyNTR9.7SA_jj96i_lh9vXemTs7RVOWCdQUhFTHv4U1cbobgs8

es un token digital

y lo capturo de esta forma

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var token = localStorage .getItem('Token');
    console.log('token);
    $('.menuprincipal').load('./modules/menu.html');
    $('#logo').load('./modules/logo.html');
});
```

no se que mas hacer, estoy intentando con localstorage y tambien sale error, no puedo usar php

Comment: ¿Qué error te aparece?

Comment: no me sale ningun error, solamene me sale null

Comment: Es pp4que lo mandas con sessionStorage  y luego lo quieres leer con localstorage.en document.ready cambia el.localStorage por sessionStorage.

Comment: Si estas abriendo una ventana independiente no te sirve sessionStorage. Utiliza en este caso localStorage o una cookie.

Comment: Otro punto asigna el sessiin o local storage antes de cambiar el Windows.location porque abajo de este es demasiado tarde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas asignando el token después de cambiar el locación :

```
var win = window.location = urlactual+'vistas/menu.html';
win.focus();
sessionStorage.setItem("Token",token);
```

Debería ser asi:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("Token",token);
var win = window.location = rlactual+'vistas/menu.html';
win.focus();
```

Asegúrate que el lea lo haga de sessionStore. Si se abre otra ventana creará otra sesión. Utiliza localStore.

Comment: Mompa eso si me dio, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu código, eliminaría el espacio que hay en el segundo fragmento en la segunda línea: `var token = localStorage .getItem('Token');` a `var token = localStorage.getItem('Token');`.

Por otro lado, en la tercera línea del mismo fragmento tienes una cadena con una comilla abierta pero sin cerrar. Solucionado:

```js
var token = localStorage.getItem("Token");
console.log("TOKEN: "+ token);
```

Sobre tu ejemplo, adjunto otro:

```js
//Se guarda el valor "Nombre de la persona" con clave "nombre"
sessionStorage.setItem("nombre", "Nombre de la persona");

//El nombre es capturado por su clave ("nombre")
var nombre = sessionStorage.getItem("nombre");

//Se muestra el resultado
console.log(nombre);
```

Si te sigue apareciendo `null`, posiblemente el token que le pasas de alguna forma sea nulo. De todos modos, en ambos fragmentos hay código mal escrito que te puede dar errores aún así.

Comment: nada, sigue siendo null

Comment: var win = window.location = urlactual+'vistas/menu.html';

win.focus();

sessionStorage.setItem("Token",token);


var token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
console.log("TOKEN: "+ token);

Comment: Evita igualar, quedate solo con las líneas en un archivo HTML aparte: toke="VALOR_DEL_TOKEN"; sessionStorage.setItem("Token",token); var token = sessionStorage.getItem("Token"); console.log("TOKEN: "+ token);

Comment: no nada, intente hasta quemando un dato asi como lo tienes y obtiene un null

Comment: Publica tu pregunta con un código funcional y comentado, de ese modo te puedo ayudar. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Al hacer el `setItem` estás utilizando sessionStorage pero al hacer el `getItem` utilizas localStorage.

Debes utilizar el mismo storage para `setItem` y `getItem`